# How to disable auto-scrolling of tableview when textfield editing time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have one `UITableview` and i added that tableview as `TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView`, i have 2 `UITextField` and Two labels , one question and Two textfields for score 1 and score 3, if i put scores on textfield i need to update the total label in the tableview cell. Now am i entering the score for last question is present in the tableview, that time it automatically scrolling to the top. i need to stay back to current position untill i pressed done button.

My code is

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange:(id)sender
{
    CGPoint textFieldPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableHSEMonthlyReport];
    NSIndexPath *txtIndPath = [self.tableHSEMonthlyReport indexPathForRowAtPoint:textFieldPoint];
    UITextField * textField = (UITextField*)sender;
    NSInteger txtTag = textField.tag;
    NSString * newString = textField.text;

    if (txtIndPath.section==0)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
            //Background Thread
            [[HSEAppData appData].arrayMonthlyGeneralQustion replaceObjectAtIndex:txtIndPath.row withObject:dic];
            [arrayGeneralQuestions replaceObjectAtIndex:txtIndPath.row withObject:question];
            NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:txtIndPath.row inSection:txtIndPath.section];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                //Run UI Updates
                [self.tableHSEMonthlyReport beginUpdates];
                HSEMonthlyPerformanceTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableHSEMonthlyReport cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                cell.lblTotal.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Total : %@",strtotal];
                [self.tableHSEMonthlyReport endUpdates];

                self.tableHSEMonthlyReport.scrollEnabled = NO;
                self.tableHSEMonthlyReport.scrollsToTop = NO;

                [textField becomeFirstResponder];
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `UITableView` scroll beacuse of `TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView`. you can disable it for one viewcontroller

Comment: @vp2698 i tried but that time keyboard is hiding the uitableview